# How to CSS style an element, when an other specific element is following?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use the [Shariff](https://github.com/heiseonline/shariff/) solution with an statistics backend to provide visitors with an easy way to share content on social media.

Based on the data from the statistics backend, Shariff will dynamically (JavaScript) introduce a `<span class="share_count">0</span>` element to every share provider (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, ...), which has a related share count number in the statistics backend data.

Now, I would like to style every Shariff button, which does not have a `share_count` element, using only CSS.

This is how an Shariff button with a share count looks like in HTML:

```
<li class="shariff-button facebook">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F" data-rel="popup" rel="nofollow" title="Bei Facebook teilen" role="button" aria-label="Bei Facebook teilen">
    <span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span>
    <span class="share_count">12k</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

And this is how an Shariff button without a share count looks like:

```
<li class="shariff-button facebook">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F" data-rel="popup" rel="nofollow" title="Bei Facebook teilen" role="button" aria-label="Bei Facebook teilen">
    <span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

How do I select an element in CSS only when it has an specific following (not a child) element.

**How do I center the Shariff button icons, which Shariff button does not have a share count?**

```js
// This is only a dummy to demonstrate the runtime manipulations done by Shariff.
setTimeout( function(){ 
  $(".shariff-container .shariff-button:not(.twitter):not(.whatsapp):not(.telegram):not(.threema):not(.linkedin):not(.tumblr):not(.mail):not(.print):not(.info)").each(function(){ 
    $(this).find("span").after('<span class="share_count">12k</span>')
  });
}, 10 );
```

```css
.shariff-container { text-align: center; }
.shariff { display: inline-block; text-align: left; }
.shariff-heading { font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; }
.shariff-button a { padding-left: 8px; }
.shariff-button.info a { padding-left: 0; }
@media print { .shariff-container { display: none; } }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shariff@3.2.1/dist/shariff.complete.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shariff@3.2.1/dist/shariff.complete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<aside class="shariff-container">
  <div class="shariff-heading">Share on social media</div>
  <div class="shariff" data-button-style="icon-count" data-lang="de" data-url="https://example.com/" data-twitter-via="twitter-handle" data-title="Site Title" data-mail-subject="mail subject" data-mail-body="mail body" data-mail-url="mailto:" data-services="[&quot;facebook&quot;,&quot;twitter&quot;,&quot;whatsapp&quot;,&quot;telegram&quot;,&quot;threema&quot;,&quot;linkedin&quot;,&quot;xing&quot;,&quot;reddit&quot;,&quot;tumblr&quot;,&quot;pinterest&quot;,&quot;mail&quot;,&quot;print&quot;,&quot;info&quot;]"></div>
</aside>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ask a bit of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). I would just tweak your flex layout a bit.

```js
// This is only a dummy to demonstrate the runtime manipulations done by Shariff.
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".shariff-container .shariff-button:not(.twitter):not(.whatsapp):not(.telegram):not(.threema):not(.linkedin):not(.tumblr):not(.mail):not(.print):not(.info)").each(function() {
    $(this).find("span").after('<span class="share_count">12k</span>')
  });
}, 10);
```

```css
.shariff-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.shariff {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* start changes ******************************/
body .shariff li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body .shariff li .share_count {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
/* end changes ********************************/

.shariff-heading {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.shariff-button a {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.shariff-button.info a {
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media print {
  .shariff-container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shariff@3.2.1/dist/shariff.complete.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shariff@3.2.1/dist/shariff.complete.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<aside class="shariff-container">
  <div class="shariff-heading">Share on social media</div>
  <div class="shariff" data-button-style="icon-count" data-lang="de" data-url="https://example.com/" data-twitter-via="twitter-handle" data-title="Site Title" data-mail-subject="mail subject" data-mail-body="mail body" data-mail-url="mailto:" data-services="[&quot;facebook&quot;,&quot;twitter&quot;,&quot;whatsapp&quot;,&quot;telegram&quot;,&quot;threema&quot;,&quot;linkedin&quot;,&quot;xing&quot;,&quot;reddit&quot;,&quot;tumblr&quot;,&quot;pinterest&quot;,&quot;mail&quot;,&quot;print&quot;,&quot;info&quot;]"></div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do

```
.shariff-button:not(:has(.share_count)){}
```

Comment: `:has()` is (currently) only supported on Safary browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a system like this:
`.shariff-button:not(.share_count_div) {}`

so just if it has also the class `share_count_div` it will run the style snippet

Comment: Its okay, it doesn't matter